# How close possibility to add new data in H2?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2, readonly

I have a problem. After adding some data to database, I need to set read-only mode for whole DB. What is the easiest way to do that using h2 embedded DB with driver manager (jdbc)?

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + "./"+dbName, "hereIsUser", "hereIsPassword");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can open the whole database in read-only mode by appending `;ACCESS_MODE_DATA=r` to the JDBC URL (`"jdbc:h2:" + "./" + dbName + ";ACCESS_MODE_DATA=r"` in your case.
2. You can create a separate user (`CREATE USER userName PASSWORD 'some_password'`) and give it only the `SELECT` grants (`GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA nameOfYourSchema TO userName`) and use that user.